# Disable reset in HTML5 Canvas when Width/Height is set

Tags: html, canvas

My scenario is that the Canvas width / height is changed dynamically, And I dont want to reset the Canvas. Instead I use the clearRect() as I know the bounds in which the rectangle has to be cleared.

1. Is there a way to disable the resetting of canvas when Width/Height is set again?
2. Is there a way to save the previous state and just load it back to the canvas exactly without re-drawing it?

Comment: You can't prevent the canvas from resetting when you resize it. You will have to save it, resize it, then restore what you saved.

Comment: I think it is kind of odd, anyway I found a way by using GetImageData/PutImageData to save/restore, this helps for now. What I was looking for is that the canvas doesn't redraw unless the user specifies it, that would be more control in the way canvas reacts to user changes.

Answer (score 5):

1. I'm afraid there's no way to disable this, it is built into the canvas spec.

   Section 4.8.11:

   > When the canvas element is created, and subsequently whenever the width and height attributes are set (whether to a new value or to the previous value), the bitmap and any associated contexts must be cleared back to their initial state and reinitialized with the newly specified coordinate space dimensions.
2. Yes, and GetImageData/PutImageData is one way but it is probably much slower than the following way:

   Let's say your canvas is called `realCanvas`. Make a second canvas (we'll call it `fakeCanvas`) that is as large as you ever intend your real canvas to be, but only make it in javascript code and never add it to the document (so no one will ever see it).

   Then, right before you resize `realCanvas`, do this operation:

   ```
   fakeCanvasContext.drawImage(realCanvas, 0, 0);
   ```

   This will draw one entire canvas to another and it will happen very quickly from a performance perspective.

   Once you are done with the resize you can draw the contents of fakeCanvas back onto your realCanvas.

   ```
   realCanvasContext.drawImage(fakeCanvas, 0, 0);
   ```

   And that's it!

   If you want to get technical, you can speed up my way even more by doing this for the second draw:

   ```
   realCanvasContext.drawImage(fakeCanvas,
       0, 0, realCanvas.width, realCanvas.height,
       0, 0, realCanvas.width, realCanvas.height);`
   ```

   That way you are only copying the part that can fit onto `realCanvas`. Please note that I haven't tested the code I wrote so there might be a syntax error or two.

Comment: I tried out your suggestion, My scenario is quite different and it is not about resizing the canvas. It is kind of a trader grid scenario where the updates in the canvas are like for every 250ms, and I do get an OK performance around 8 - 20% CPU usage with your approach, it was almost same as the Get/Put imagedata. But anyway the drawImage approach should help me out in other scenarios.

The specification is quite odd, there should be a reset() method that should reset the canvas, by changing the width/height the canvas should just increase/decrease the pixels instead of reinit itself.